# Is transit visa required to transit through Reykjavik (KEF)?

Tags: visas, transit, iceland, icelandair, kef

I have a flight on April 27 from Delhi(DEL) to Toronto (YYZ) via Paris Charles De Gualle (layover of 4 hours 25 minutes) and next layover at Reykjavik(KEF) for 1 hour 30 minutes. Do I need to take transit visa? [Plz find the screenshot of my flight timings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9GaJ.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9GaJ.jpg)

Comment: What is your citizenship? What type of Visas do you have already ?

Comment: I am an Indian citizen and currently have a study permit for Canada.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are allowed to enter the Schengen area without a visa, I assume you are not, you do not only need a transit visa, but a completely regular Schengen visa for that itinerary since you have two transit within the Schengen area.

You will have to clear immigration and enter the Schengen area in Paris and then later clear immigration and leave the Schengen are in Reykjavik.

Comment: Than you so much for your reply!